# Rcpp modules confusion

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm having trouble getting `RCPP_MODULE` to work from `Rcpp::Rcpp.package.skeleton()` and am not sure what I'm missing. I appended the following code to `rcpp_hello_world.cpp` in my package `ab`:

```
class A {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
public:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  int foo() {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    return 1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
};                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
RCPP_MODULE(ab_module) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  class_<A>("A").                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    constructor().                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    method("foo", &A::foo);                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
}
```

I then run `Rcpp::compileAttributes()` and `R CMD` `build` and `INSTALL` the package. Then:

```
R> library(ab)
R> Rcpp::Module('ab_module', inline::getDynLib('ab'))
Uninitialized module named "ab_module" from package "ab"
Uninitialized module named "ab_module" from package "~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/ab/libs/ab.so"
Uninitialized module named "ab_module" from package "FALSE"
Uninitialized module named "ab_module" from package "<pointer: 0x5578d469d0e0>"
Uninitialized module named "ab_module" from package "<pointer: 0x5578d35ff690>"
R> rcpp_hello_world()
[[1]]
[1] "foo" "bar"

[[2]]
[1] 0 1

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=nl_NL.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=nl_NL.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=nl_NL.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=nl_NL.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ab_1.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.3 inline_0.3.15  Rcpp_1.0.5
```

How can I initialize the module?

Other Rcpp code does work on this machine but I fail to narrow down the differences between those packages and this code.

I tried putting putting `import(Rcpp)` or `importFrom(Rcpp, evalCpp)` in `NAMESPACE` to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two or three quick comments:

1. It is indeed tricky as Rcpp Modules *predates* Rcpp Attributes.
2. Module initialization happens *from an R call*.  Do you have

   `loadModule("AB_module", TRUE)`

   somewhere?  Note that it can be in *any* file in `R/`, you are *not*
   required to put it in `.onLoad()`.
3. Updating a package last weekend I also got reminded that you then still may have to add the `R_init_ab(DllInfo *dll)` call with `R_CallMethodDef()`. I can probably point you to an example.

So in sum, we probably needs a simply quickstart vignette for 'how to start a Modules package in 2020'.  And/or rewrite the existing vignette.

Comment: I think I found an easy alternative solution.

Comment: No, it is the *same*. I suggested you add `loadModule(modulenamehere, TRUE)` and you did.  How is that "alternative" ?

Comment: You're right, alternative to 3. I'm happy that looking at 3 isn't necessary and it seems that it's not required to happen in `.onLoad()` either. My final note in the answer puzzles me though. Why can't `loadModule()` not be done interactively?

Comment: Why should it be? _You are writing a package_ and for that (to please `R CMD check`) _you will also need the `R_init_*` business_.  Now I can either help you with that, or you can go on thinking you know better and guess your way around.  Your call.  (And I suggest deleting the non-answer.)

Comment: Dropped the answer, appearance anywhere in the package itself is fine. I'm passing `R CMD check` after adding `methods` to the import` with just `Rcpp::loadModule('mod_ab', TRUE)` in a package R-file. However, this package is very simple. When does the lacking `R_init_*`  bite? If you have more information on that I appreciate it. Good to mentio to other reader: A gotcha to be aware is that I found in combination with roxygen2: I had to add `//' @export` to the class. This makes sense if you think about it but it is different from the `Module()` approach.

Comment: Maybe try `R CMD check --as-cran`. It just hit me last weekend updating the (dormant, old trial) package RcppXts (and it had hit me several times before with other packages using Modules). And yes -- we _definitely_ need a pass over the vignette to update it.  I _thought_ we had always said fairly clearly that you'd want Modules in a package only.  But apparently not...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218580/discussion-between-bob-jansen-and-dirk-eddelbuettel).